# What is the way to turn on optimization in flash professional?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, optimization, compiler-construction, flash-cs5

I did few speed checks and looks like compiler in flash professional doesn't do optimizations. I am using flash professional cs5.5. Is there a way in flash professional to turn on compiler optimizations?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean option version between release and debugging version in Flash Professional?

Adobe offical note:

> When compiling your project in Flash Professional, you do not have the option of choosing between release and debugging version. The compiled SWF file is a release version by default.

[Adobe link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-315cd077124319488fd-7ffe.html)

Hope useful to you. :)

Comment: no i meant optimization flag when compiling...i checked it doesnt optimize out things like for example check using list.length in loop and take that outside the loop you see performance difference. So,in that sense my question was just like gcc does flash have an option of optimization that optimizes things like those.